windeployqt creates an exe that doesn't work
I made a simple app that I can build on Ubuntu and Mac with "make", but on Windows I have these errors when I try to build the app with QT Creator.
I did this:

Open Qt Creator.
Create a New Project: Create Project -> Application -> Qt Widgets Application
Copy sources from gui/: mainwindow.h, mainwindow.cpp, and main.cpp
Build: Build -> Build Project "redatamguiwindows"

After installing Chocolatey with choco install directx and copying the DLLs to Z:\redatamguiwindows\build\Desktop_Qt_6_7_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug, I ran
$vcInstallDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("VCINSTALLDIR", $vcInstallDir, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
cd Z:\redatamguiwindows\build\Desktop_Qt_6_7_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug
& "C:\Qt\6.7.2\mingw_64\bin\windeployqt.exe" redatamguiwindows.exe

it says "Warning: Cannot find any version of the dxcompiler.dll and dxil.dll."
and then when I open the exe it says "the exe still fails with "the procedure entry point..."
do you have any idea of how to fix this?
I am using Qt 6.7 downloaded from https://d13lb3tujbc8s0.cloudfront.net/onlineinstallers/qt-online-installer-windows-x64-4.8.0.exe and I installed the default Qt Desktop.

"the exe still fails with "the procedure entry point..." Sounds like a dll conflict / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell

The installation for MinGW based Qt should not use msvc at all.

but I installed everything as default, do I have to reinstall Qt in a diferent way? I just installed Windows for this

My point was all the vcInstallDir ... steps should not be used to deploy a MinGW based application. You should have no mention of msvc when deploying MinGW. These 2 compilers are incompatible for c++ based applications.

On Windows, Qt offers two options, MingGW and MSVC. If your code contains C++17 or higher specific functions, then you have to use the MSVC option with Visual Studio installed.
In my previous question, I finally made sure that when installing from https://d13lb3tujbc8s0.cloudfront.net/onlineinstallers/qt-online-installer-windows-x64-4.8.0.exe I selected "Qt 5 for MSVC 2019 64-bit"
Then I installed directX with choco install directx -y. I cannot use choco install qt5-default as it is MinGW and my app uses C++17 methods.
Then I could build my app with
mkdir build
cd Z:\redatamguiwindows\build
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"
cmake --build . --config Release
& "C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\windeployqt.exe" --release .\Release\redatamgui.exe

The code is here https://github.com/pachadotdev/redatam-converter/tree/main/redatamguiwindows


In Windows, Qt offers two options, MingGW and MSVC. If your code contains C++17 > or higher specific functions, then you have to use the MSVC option with Visual > Studio installed.


I am trying to find where this information can be validated on the QT site and I didn't find any evidence.  Build and running C++17 using MinGW seems to be working but there does seem to be a problem with inclusion of some dependencies.

That is what I saw in the installer, you can click either Qt MingGW or Qt MSVC. The choco installation is only MingGW. Because of this, I will continue to build my Windows binary on virtualbox until I can find a way to install Qt simulating the clicks with gh-actions.

"Visual Studio installed" i think you mean you need to install the ms build Tools and not the whole IDE
